# PowerShell Active Directory Objects Writable Properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm working on a script to synchronize two Active Directory forests (Production and QA, if you don't understand why, it doesn't matter, I need to do it). The problem I've run into is filtering properties to only writable and only those that are normally writable. From the MMC "Active Directory Users and Computers" I can look at the Attribute Editor tab and filter the attributes to "Show only writable attributes". This displays a completely different list than what I get viewing the same object with a PowerShell command.

I don't want to synchronize or attempt to modify attributes like nTSecurityDescriptor, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, etc. I also don't want to try developing and maintaining a static list for each object class (OU, User, Group).

Is there a better way to retrieve the properties that are writable for a given AD object?

Here is an example of the problem with an OU object:

```
PS E:\Powershell> $ou | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.Definition.Contains("set;")}

   TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit

Name                            MemberType Definition
----                            ---------- ----------
City                            Property   System.String City {get;set;}
Country                         Property   System.String Country {get;set;}
Description                     Property   System.String Description {get;set;}
DisplayName                     Property   System.String DisplayName {get;set;}
DistinguishedName               Property   System.String DistinguishedName {get;set;}
l                               Property   System.String l {get;set;}
ManagedBy                       Property   System.String ManagedBy {get;set;}
nTSecurityDescriptor            Property   System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity nTSecurityDescriptor {get...
ObjectClass                     Property   System.String ObjectClass {get;set;}
ObjectGUID                      Property   System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...
ou                              Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection ou {get;set;}
PostalCode                      Property   System.String PostalCode {get;set;}
ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion Property   System.Boolean ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion {get;set;}
PSShowComputerName              Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection PSShowCompu...
State                           Property   System.String State {get;set;}
StreetAddress                   Property   System.String StreetAddress {get;set;}
WriteDebugStream                Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection WriteDebugS...
WriteErrorStream                Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection WriteErrorS...
WriteInformationStream          Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection WriteInform...
WriteVerboseStream              Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection WriteVerbos...
WriteWarningStream              Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection WriteWarnin...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, your example code, plus @tommymaynard's code essentially will give you a raw list of settable properties.

The "better" way to get the list of settable properties is to refer to the [Set-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps) documentation, which lists everything you can set and more importantly *how* to set them. Some properties need Hashtables and other parameters (`-Add`, `-Clear`, etc.) to set them properly.

Unfortunately, you will end up having 3 different lists for OU, User, and Groups simply because of the fact that they are 3 different object types, and they each have different properties and different cmdlets for setting properties.

If this sounds like a lot of manual work, and lists... yes it is. If the end goal is to synchronize between two domains, use Microsoft's [Active Directory Migration Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56570). It is designed to synchronize two different domains with one way sync, two way sync, password sync, SID history, etc. Way easier than doing it manually.

Comment: Because our schema has custom attributes and classes, and we need to synchronize OUs, it didn't look like the AD migration tool would work. I agree that this is simply going to be a lot of static management, I'll probably use CSV files to control which attributes get synced for which object type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Do yourself a favor and after you've run the below command once, remove the final Select-Object. After that, remove the Where-Object. Really take some time to understand what's happening here as you back yourself though these commands. You might even start at the beginning too and run just the Get-ADOrganizationalUnit command, then add the Select-Object, then add the ForEach-Object, etc. This should get you what you need.

```
PS> Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object {$_.psobject.properties} | Where-Object {$_.IsSettable -eq $true} | Select-Object -Property Name,IsSettable
```

Note: In my example, I only returned the first Organizational Unit. Keep that in mind if you move this into your own code.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same list as above, albeit in a different format. It isn't that I can't get the IsSettable properties, There are settable properties that normally wouldn't be seen, like 'nTsecurityDescriptor'. Somehow these properties are filtered out using MMC, I'm guessing there is a flag or something hidden. I'm thinking that I'm simply going to have to do this in a static manner, which I really don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

For all that you are after, you'd want to use a different cmdlet with a slight twist on it.

For example:

```
(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *)[0] |  Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.Definition.Contains("set;")} | Format-Table -AutoSize


   TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit

Name              MemberType Definition                                                                                                                         
----              ---------- ----------                                                                                                                         
City              Property   System.String City {get;set;}                                                                                                      
Country           Property   System.String Country {get;set;}                                                                                                   
DistinguishedName Property   System.String DistinguishedName {get;set;}                                                                                         
ManagedBy         Property   System.String ManagedBy {get;set;}                                                                                                 
ObjectClass       Property   System.String ObjectClass {get;set;}                                                                                               
ObjectGUID        Property   System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] ObjectGUID {get;set;}
PostalCode        Property   System.String PostalCode {get;set;}                                                                                                
State             Property   System.String State {get;set;}                                                                                                     
StreetAddress     Property   System.String StreetAddress {get;set;} 

((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *)[0] |  Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.Definition.Contains("set;")}).Count
 9


(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties *)[0] |  Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.Definition.Contains("set;")} | Format-Table -AutoSize

   TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit

Name                            MemberType Definition                                                                                                                 
----                            ---------- ----------                                                                                                                 
City                            Property   System.String City {get;set;}                                                                                              
Country                         Property   System.String Country {get;set;}                                                                                           
Description                     Property   System.String Description {get;set;}                                                                                       
DisplayName                     Property   System.String DisplayName {get;set;}                                                                                       
DistinguishedName               Property   System.String DistinguishedName {get;set;}                                                                                 
gPLink                          Property   System.String gPLink {get;set;}                                                                                            
isCriticalSystemObject          Property   System.Boolean isCriticalSystemObject {get;set;}                                                                           
ManagedBy                       Property   System.String ManagedBy {get;set;}                                                                                         
nTSecurityDescriptor            Property   System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity nTSecurityDescriptor {get;set;}                                           
ObjectClass                     Property   System.String ObjectClass {get;set;}                                                                                       
ObjectGUID                      Property   System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] ObjectGUID...
ou                              Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection ou {get;set;}                                               
PostalCode                      Property   System.String PostalCode {get;set;}                                                                                        
ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion Property   System.Boolean ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion {get;set;}                                                                  
showInAdvancedViewOnly          Property   System.Boolean showInAdvancedViewOnly {get;set;}                                                                           
State                           Property   System.String State {get;set;}                                                                                             
StreetAddress                   Property   System.String StreetAddress {get;set;} 

((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties *)[0] |  Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.Definition.Contains("set;")}).Count

17
```

Playing with the AD: Drive for Fun and Profit

```
Push-Location -Path 'ad:\'
Get-ChildItem
Get-ChildItem -Path (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *)[0] -Properties *
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/18/playing-with-the-ad-drive-for-fun-and-profit

```
Get-ChildItem -Path (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *)[0] -Properties * | Get-Member | Format-Table -AutoSize
(Get-ChildItem -Path (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *)[0] -Properties * | Get-Member | Format-Table -AutoSize).Count

62

   TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject

Name                          MemberType            Definition                                                                                                        
----                          ----------            ----------                                                                                                        
Contains                      Method                bool Contains(string propertyName)                                                                                
Equals                        Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                    
GetEnumerator                 Method                System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()                                                          
GetHashCode                   Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                                                 
GetType                       Method                type GetType()                                                                                                    
ToString                      Method                string ToString()                                                                                                 
PSChildName                   NoteProperty          System.String PSChildName=CN=SATLDC01                                                                             
PSDrive                       NoteProperty          Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Provider.ADDriveInfo PSDrive=AD                                              
PSIsContainer                 NoteProperty          System.Boolean PSIsContainer=True                                                                                 
PSParentPath                  NoteProperty          System.String PSParentPath=Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management\ActiveDirectory:://RootDSE/OU=Domain Controller...
PSPath                        NoteProperty          System.String PSPath=Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management\ActiveDirectory:://RootDSE/CN=SATLDC01,OU=Domain Cont...
PSProvider                    NoteProperty          System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management\ActiveDirectory         
Item                          ParameterizedProperty Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection Item(string propertyName) {get;}                   
accountExpires                Property              System.Int64 accountExpires {get;set;}                                                                            
AddedProperties               Property              System.Collections.Generic.ICollection[string] AddedProperties {get;}                                             
badPasswordTime               Property              System.Int64 badPasswordTime {get;set;}                                                                           
badPwdCount                   Property              System.Int32 badPwdCount {get;set;}                                                                               
cn                            Property              System.String cn {get;}                                                                                           
codePage                      Property              System.Int32 codePage {get;set;}                                                                                  
countryCode                   Property              System.Int32 countryCode {get;set;}                                                                               
distinguishedName             Property              System.String distinguishedName {get;set;}                                                                        
dNSHostName                   Property              System.String dNSHostName {get;set;}                                                                              
dSCorePropagationData         Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection dSCorePropagationData {get;}                       
instanceType                  Property              System.Int32 instanceType {get;}                                                                                  
isCriticalSystemObject        Property              System.Boolean isCriticalSystemObject {get;set;}                                                                  
lastLogoff                    Property              System.Int64 lastLogoff {get;set;}                                                                                
lastLogon                     Property              System.Int64 lastLogon {get;set;}                                                                                 
lastLogonTimestamp            Property              System.Int64 lastLogonTimestamp {get;set;}                                                                        
localPolicyFlags              Property              System.Int32 localPolicyFlags {get;set;}                                                                          
logonCount                    Property              System.Int32 logonCount {get;set;}                                                                                
memberOf                      Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection memberOf {get;}                                    
ModifiedProperties            Property              System.Collections.Generic.ICollection[string] ModifiedProperties {get;}                                          
msDFSR-ComputerReferenceBL    Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection msDFSR-ComputerReferenceBL {get;}                  
msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes Property              System.Int32 msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes {get;set;}                                                             
name                          Property              System.String name {get;}                                                                                         
nTSecurityDescriptor          Property              System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity nTSecurityDescriptor {get;set;}                                  
objectCategory                Property              System.String objectCategory {get;}                                                                               
objectClass                   Property              System.String objectClass {get;set;}                                                                              
objectGUID                    Property              System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] o...
objectSid                     Property              System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier objectSid {get;}                                                     
operatingSystem               Property              System.String operatingSystem {get;set;}                                                                          
operatingSystemVersion        Property              System.String operatingSystemVersion {get;set;}                                                                   
primaryGroupID                Property              System.Int32 primaryGroupID {get;set;}                                                                            
PropertyCount                 Property              int PropertyCount {get;}                                                                                          
PropertyNames                 Property              System.Collections.ICollection PropertyNames {get;}                                                               
pwdLastSet                    Property              System.Int64 pwdLastSet {get;set;}                                                                                
RemovedProperties             Property              System.Collections.Generic.ICollection[string] RemovedProperties {get;}                                           
rIDSetReferences              Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection rIDSetReferences {get;}                            
sAMAccountName                Property              System.String sAMAccountName {get;set;}                                                                           
sAMAccountType                Property              System.Int32 sAMAccountType {get;set;}                                                                            
serverReferenceBL             Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection serverReferenceBL {get;}                           
servicePrincipalName          Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection servicePrincipalName {get;set;}                    
userAccountControl            Property              System.Int32 userAccountControl {get;set;}                                                                        
userCertificate               Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection userCertificate {get;set;}                         
uSNChanged                    Property              System.Int64 uSNChanged {get;}                                                                                    
uSNCreated                    Property              System.Int64 uSNCreated {get;}                                                                                    
whenChanged                   Property              System.DateTime whenChanged {get;}                                                                                
whenCreated                   Property              System.DateTime whenCreated {get;} 

Get-ChildItem -Path (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *)[0] -Properties * | Get-Member | Where {$_.Definition.Contains("set;")} | Format-Table -AutoSize
(Get-ChildItem -Path (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *)[0] -Properties * | Get-Member | Where {$_.Definition.Contains("set;")} | Format-Table -AutoSize).Count

30
   TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject

Name                          MemberType Definition                                                                                                                   
----                          ---------- ----------                                                                                                                   
accountExpires                Property   System.Int64 accountExpires {get;set;}                                                                                       
badPasswordTime               Property   System.Int64 badPasswordTime {get;set;}                                                                                      
badPwdCount                   Property   System.Int32 badPwdCount {get;set;}                                                                                          
codePage                      Property   System.Int32 codePage {get;set;}                                                                                             
countryCode                   Property   System.Int32 countryCode {get;set;}                                                                                          
distinguishedName             Property   System.String distinguishedName {get;set;}                                                                                   
dNSHostName                   Property   System.String dNSHostName {get;set;}                                                                                         
isCriticalSystemObject        Property   System.Boolean isCriticalSystemObject {get;set;}                                                                             
lastLogoff                    Property   System.Int64 lastLogoff {get;set;}                                                                                           
lastLogon                     Property   System.Int64 lastLogon {get;set;}                                                                                            
lastLogonTimestamp            Property   System.Int64 lastLogonTimestamp {get;set;}                                                                                   
localPolicyFlags              Property   System.Int32 localPolicyFlags {get;set;}                                                                                     
logonCount                    Property   System.Int32 logonCount {get;set;}                                                                                           
msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes Property   System.Int32 msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes {get;set;}                                                                        
nTSecurityDescriptor          Property   System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity nTSecurityDescriptor {get;set;}                                             
objectClass                   Property   System.String objectClass {get;set;}                                                                                         
objectGUID                    Property   System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] objectGUID {...
operatingSystem               Property   System.String operatingSystem {get;set;}                                                                                     
operatingSystemVersion        Property   System.String operatingSystemVersion {get;set;}                                                                              
primaryGroupID                Property   System.Int32 primaryGroupID {get;set;}                                                                                       
pwdLastSet                    Property   System.Int64 pwdLastSet {get;set;}                                                                                           
sAMAccountName                Property   System.String sAMAccountName {get;set;}                                                                                      
sAMAccountType                Property   System.Int32 sAMAccountType {get;set;}                                                                                       
servicePrincipalName          Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection servicePrincipalName {get;set;}                               
userAccountControl            Property   System.Int32 userAccountControl {get;set;}                                                                                   
userCertificate               Property   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection userCertificate {get;set;}
```